# extend nodejs server obj

Tags: node.js, module, express

I use express.js, and I like the implementation of routes, events, etc being like:

```
    var app = express.createServer();

    // events

    app.emit('auth.login', req, res, next, {
        email : 'foo@bar.com',
        password: '1234'
    });

    app.on('auth.login', function(req, res, next, data){ 
        console.log(data.email, data.password);
        // ... 
    });
```

Now I would like to extend the server instance with my own obj (in the way 'emit' and 'on' are implemented), for example 'actions' - so that this might be possible:

```
    // actions

    app.actions('auth.login', req, res, next, {
    // ...
    });

    app.done('auth.login', function(req, res, next, data){ 
        // ... 
    });
```

The reason I would love to have it implemented like this is, that I would like to trigger various async actions on certain events.

I don't know how to do that? Any suggestions?

Comment: "actions" can be implemented as middleware for the routes, but in order to use "done" I think the only way is to call it manually when everything's done in the route, for ex done(req, res, next).. I'm not sure if there's a cleaner way to implement done()

Comment: Is the only motivation here to rename methods emit/on to actions/done? Did not get the question...